# Critical Bug Session is not destroying in Kohana 3.x

Tags: php, kohana

I am developing one of web application in kohanaphp latest version. While user logged into application, I set the session as usually. Everything fine. Once i logout the application which clear the session.

Then I am checking in all functions whether user id exist, if it exist, it will work, otherwise it will goes to login page.

But my problem is that, I logged out the profile, while user click on the browser back button, it goes to profiles pages. It should not happened. It should goes to login page. But while user refresh the page it redirect to user login page.

Same things working in older version. But not in latest version.

Critical Bug is Session is not destroying in Kohana 3.x

Can you please any one provide the solution.

Comment: It's the browser giving you a cached page? Anyway, since the user is logged out he cannot save anything. If you change to https the browser should not cache pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add this headers,

```
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
 header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
 header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a cached page they are seeing and not a re-request to the server.